# Making code generic

Tags: shell

I have one script **/location/centers_password.sh** in which I have below lines of code :

```
if [ "$DC" = "sl" ]
then
    arg1=`echo -n $Center|wc -m`
    if [ $arg1 -gt 3 ]
    then
        grep "^$Center" /location/.CenterPassword.file.sdi.sl
        grep "^$Center" /location/.CenterPassword_xel.file.sdi.sl
    else
         grep "^$Center" /location/.CenterPassword.file.sl
         grep "^$Center" /location/.CenterPassword_xel.file.sl
         grep "^$Center" /location/.sftpPasswod.file.sl
    fi
elif [ "$DC" = "ch" ]
then
    arg1=`echo -n $Center|wc -m`
    if [ $arg1 -gt 3 ]
    then
        grep "^$Center" /location/.CenterPassword.file.sdi.ch
        grep "^$Center" /location/.CenterPassword_xel.file.sdi.ch
    else
         grep "^$Center" /location/.CenterPassword.file.ch
         grep "^$Center" /location/.CenterPassword_xel.file.ch
         grep "^$Center" /location/.sftpPasswod.file.ch
    fi
```

What I am doing here is, when I execute this code it reads the datacenter name .CenterPassword.file.sdi.ch file. If I explain more, suppose the datacenter starts from 'sl' it reads .CenterPassword.file.sdi.sl file and fetch the password and suppose datacenter starts from 'ch' it reads .CenterPassword.file.sdi.ch and fetch the password.

My requirement is to make this code generic. This file should read the hostname and if the hostname's initial two letter match with **.CenterPassword.file.sdi.ch** file last two letters (in this example, should match with 'ch') it should fetch the password. Please help to do this.

Comment: Like `grep "^$Center" /location/.CenterPassword.file.sdi.$DC`?

Comment: @pacholik If we can achieve this with if statement calling hostname and that hostname pattern (first two letters)should match with .CenterPassword.file.sdi.ch file last two characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem 1: get the first two letters of the hostname:

```
DC=`hostname | cut -b1,2`
```

Problem 2: Use that to read the right filenames:

You could just use your long list of if/else statements (how many datacenters can there be?), but as shell lets you build a filename on the fly, there's no need.

```
grep "^Center" /location/.CenterPassword.file.sdi.$DC
```

The `$DC` will add the proper two-letter suffix to the filename.